# Error loading Google App Engine backup on BigQuery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

In my GAE App I just do a datastore_backup for all Kinds.

When I try to load it to BigQuery almost Kinds was successfully loaded however with one Kind I have this error:

> invalid - Invalid field name "rows.pedido_automatico". Fields must
>   contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or
>   underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

My GAE Kind:

```
class StockRow(ndb.Model):
  pedido_automatico = ndb.StringProperty(default="N",choices=set(["S","N"]))

class Stock(ndb.Model):
  rows = ndb.StructuredProperty(SemAlmacenPedidoRutaRow, repeated=True)
```

Is this a known bug ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that we've got a fix for internally and should be in our next release.